# Fail to start puppeter

Tags: typescript, npm, puppeteer, node-modules

I have installed every dependencie using npm i but still i am seeing this error

i expected it to show a qr code . but it is showing this error
C:\Users\Maaz\Desktop\Development\whatsapp-chatgpt\node_modules\whatsapp-web.js\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\node\Launcher.js:105
throw new Error(missingText);
^

Error: Could not find expected browser (chrome) locally. Run `npm install` to download the correct Chromium revision (982053).
at ChromeLauncher.launch (C:\Users\Maaz\Desktop\Development\whatsapp-chatgpt\node_modules\whatsapp-web.js\node_modules\puppeteer\src\node\Launcher.ts:146:30)
at PuppeteerNode.launch (C:\Users\Maaz\Desktop\Development\whatsapp-chatgpt\node_modules\whatsapp-web.js\node_modules\puppeteer\src\node\Puppeteer.ts:155:27)
at Client.initialize (C:\Users\Maaz\Desktop\Development\whatsapp-chatgpt\node_modules\whatsapp-web.js\src\Client.js:100:39)

Comment: Can you please share some codes and what you have try and what you want.

Comment: Sure check this https://github.com/Maaz4f/whatsapp-chatgpt code i use it and it gives the error

Comment: Please share the code **here**.